# Как запустить файл python на удаленном сервере Windows Server 2016 (Paramiko)

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Нужно запустить скрипт py_1.py который находится на удаленном сервере в папке с:/.
Не удается таким образом запустить скрипт py_1.py. Возможно можно использовать другую библиотеку fabric?

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("167.23.44.65", username="username", password="password")
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('python c:/py_1.py')

print(ssh_stdout.read())
print(ssh_stderr.read())
```

Comment: Что значит не удаётся? Опишите наблюдаемое поведение текущего кода. Попробуйте использовать `pathlib` для win-пути, а не "c:/py_1.py"

Comment: Спасибо что быстро ответили. К сожалению ошибку не выдает, программа завершается но при этом код py_1.py не выполняется. Напишите пожалуйста что именно должно быть внутри  ssh.exec_command('text').

Comment: Я вижу у вас в коде `ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr`, какие значения они принимают?

Comment: Ошибка у вас выдается в ssh_stdout или ssh_stderr - нужно их читать.

Comment: В идеальном случае мне нужно запускать скрипт (функцию) на удаленном сервере и читать его вывод (результат вычисления функции). Код выше взят из примеров в интернете но он не работает. Прошу по возможности написать рабочий вариант для выполнения данной задачи. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
import paramiko

import os

path = os.path.abspath(r'C:/py_1.py')
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("ID", username="UN", password="PASS")
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(f'python {path}')

# print(ssh_stdin.read())
print(ssh_stdout.read())
print(ssh_stderr.read())
```

Спасибо, теперь все  работает!

Comment: Всё таки лучше использовать `pathlib`, а не `os.path` в современном питоне, но идея правильная